# WkWebview crossing notch swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i'm trying make app using webview with wkwebview
but my webview is crossing notch in iphone, how to make my webview not crossing the notch

here my view controller

[image]

and here is my code

```
var webView: WKWebView!
var popupWebView: WKWebView?
var urlPath: String = "https://twitter.com"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupWebView()
    loadWebView()
}
func setupWebView() {
    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    let prefs = WKWebpagePreferences()
    prefs.allowsContentJavaScript = true
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.preferences = preferences
    configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences = prefs
    webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
    webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshWebView(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    webView.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    webView.scrollView.bounces = true
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(webView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
    ])

}

func loadWebView() {
    logger.log("loadwebview")
    if let url = URL(string: urlPath) {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        self.view = webView
        webView.load(urlRequest)
    }
}
```

and here my result

[image]

how to make my webview under notch

update result
[image]

thanks

Comment: Add layout constraints to WebView and make them relative to `safearealayoutguide` that should ensure your webview wont cross over top and bottom "notch" you specified in question

Answer (score 0):

Add layout constraints to WebView and make them relative to safearealayoutguide that should ensure your webview wont cross over top and bottom "notch" you specified in question.

In your `setupWebView` replace  `view.addSubview(webView)` with these lines

```
            webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(webView)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
                                         webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
                                         webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
                                         webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)])
```

If you want your webView to overflow to bottom safe area (content below bottom notch) simply remove `safeAreaLayoutGuide` from `webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)` to `webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)`

Comment: i change to that code with `webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)`, but still not working

Comment: What is not working? Can you update your question with latest code and Screenshot?

Comment: Is content going behind stausbar after scrolling?

Comment: in twitter not, in another website after scrolling